# Applications of Non-Standard Analysis to Number Theory and Topology?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, soft-question, analytic-number-theory, nonstandard-analysis

S.E friends,

I am wondering what might be some useful applications of the non-standard analysis to the number theory and topology?  I am very interested in the set-theoretic topology and prime distributions, and I recently came across the field of non-standard analysis...The use of infinitesimal is interesting but I am not sure how can it be applied to my fields of interest.

Do infinitesimals offer different perspective to the analytic number theory and topology?

Comment: The answer is "topology can be interpreted through the lens of non-standard analysis", but I don't know very much about how to do it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes is easily rewritten to have a NSA flavor: Notice that, for $N$ infinitely large, $N!+1$ has no standard factors. Thus, the smallest prime factor of this is infinitely large, meaning there is an infinitely large prime. And we are done, for this means every standard number has a prime above it, and, by transfer, every number has a prime above it, so there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Akiva, I don't follow this argument.  The statement that every standard prime has a prime above it is not an elementary formula.  Therefore one apparently cannot apply transfer to it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Perhaps… It's been a while since I've thought hard about this stuff.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I'm not sure how to phrase the proof in the Robinson sense, but there should be an equivalent: it's definitely true that a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of infinitely many primes is the existence of a nonstandard prime. The argument above is fine for transfer in the IST sense.

Comment: @Akiva, the proof can be phrased using underflow to yield a correct argument but in this particular case I don't see that it provides any additional insight that the almost identical traditional proof does not provide.

Answer (score 5):

For an application in topology, consider Tychonoff's theorem. Tychonoff's theorem states that the product of any collection of compact topological spaces is compact with respect to the product topology.  Once the basic machinery of the hyperreal framework is in place, the proof of Tychonoff's theorem is essentially a one-liner.  The point is that there is an elegant an convenient characterisation of compactness as follows.  A space $A$ is compact if and only if every point of its natural extension $A^\ast$ is nearstandard.  Here being nearstandard for $x$ means that that there exists an infinitely close point to $x$ which belongs to $A$.

Thus, $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact because its natural extension contains infinite numbers which are therefore not infinitely close to any real number.

The interval $(0,1)$ is not compact because $(0,1)^\ast$ contains infinitesimals which are not infinitely close to any real strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3):

In number theory, I've seen occasional good use made of the *infinite* numbers. If $P$ is an infinite prime number, then the internal finite field of $P$ elements is, externally, a field of characteristic zero.

I've used facts about finite fields to construct fields of characteristic zero with nice properties, and used facts about characteristic zero fields to prove things about sufficiently large finite fields.

The first time I've seen this method is in regards to the [Ax-Kochen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Kochen_theorem): if Wikipedia's account is accurate, the main idea of the proof can be rephrased as saying that the field $\mathbb{Q}_P$ of $P$-adic numbers and the field $\mathbb{F}_P((t))$ of formal Laurent series over the finite field of $P$ elements happen to be, when viewed externally, elementary equivalent as valued fields.